# Проблема с iconContent в ObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть точки (метки), с которыми взаимодействует пользователь. Точек может быть больше ста, поэтому они загружаются на карту с помощью [ObjectManager](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager).
При нажатии на точку должно меняться содержимое точки (метки) - iconContent. Нужно просто пронумеровать нажатые.
[Полный пример описывающий проблему с некоторым решением](https://jsfiddle.net/tcwekh9m/2/).

**Вопрос: Как динамически изменить надпись внутри метки ObjectManager-а?**

Есть готовые решения для объекта Placemark (например [вот](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoobject_contextmenu)). Но точки ObjectManager-а - это не Placemark.
Обращение напрямую к свойству недостаточно, так как значение меняется, но на карте ничего не происходит.

```
placemark.properties.iconContent = "12";
```

Максимум, чего удалось добиться, это изменение содержимого, после щелчка мышью на метке и дополнительно ухода мыши с метки. Если просто щёлкнуть мышью и не двигать ей - ничего не произойдёт. Может потребоваться несколько меток нажать. То есть явно это нештатный способ. Тем не менее, достигается это двумя способами:

1. Перезагружать все точки

```
let placemarks = gObjectManager.objects.getAll();
manipulate(placemarks);
gObjectManager.objects.removeAll();
gObjectManager.objects.add(placemarks);
```

2. Или перезагружать одну нужную точку

```
function placemarkUpdate(placemark) {
    let objectId = placemark.id;
    gObjectManager.objects.remove(objectId);
    gObjectManager.objects.add(placemark);  
}
```

Можно ещё пробовать менять опции, но это всё не работает как надо. Что я делаю не так?

Поясню полный пример.

```
// сначала всё стандартно
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  // инициализируем карту
  gMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.753960, 37.620393],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: []
  });

  // инициализируем мегазагрузчик точек
  gObjectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({});
  gObjectManager.events.add('click', om_onclick); // указываем, что нам надо событие нажатия на объект           
  gMap.geoObjects.add(gObjectManager);
  
  // добавляем точки в ObjectManager (внутри функции длинный JSON, хранящий 43 точки)
  addPoints();
}

// обрабатываем событие нажатия
function om_onclick(e) {

  // здесь всё обычно - получаем объект, на который пользователь нажал мышкой
  let objectId = e.get('objectId');
  let placemark = gObjectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
  let n = gCurrentRoute.indexOf(objectId); // ищем в массиве нажатых
  if (n >= 0) {

    // если метка есть в массиве - удаляем из него
    gCurrentRoute.splice(n, 1);

  } else {                                                        

    // если нет - добавляем в массив   
    gCurrentRoute.push(objectId);

  }

  // обновляем содержимое точек
  update_labels();
}

// нерабочий вариант перенумерования всех точек
function update_labels() {

  let placemarks = gObjectManager.objects.getAll();
  placemarks.forEach(function(placemark) {
    let objectId = placemark.id;
    let n = gCurrentRoute.indexOf(objectId);
    let oldIconContent = placemark.properties.iconContent;
    if (n >= 0) {
      placemark.properties.iconContent = "" + n;
    } else {
      placemark.properties.iconContent = "";
    }               
    if (oldIconContent != placemark.properties.iconContent) {
      placemarkUpdate(placemark);   
    }
  });

}

// нерабочий вариант обновления конкретной точки
function placemarkUpdate(placemark) {
  let objectId = placemark.id;
  gObjectManager.objects.remove(objectId);
  gObjectManager.objects.add(placemark);    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала меняем содержимое метки так, как указано в вопросе:

```
placemark.properties.iconContent = "12";
```

Затем главное - вот такой способ я нашёл для перезагрузки ObjectManager на карте (обновление карты):

```
gMap.geoObjects.remove(gObjectManager);
gMap.geoObjects.add(gObjectManager);
```

Но! При этом курсор над меткой меняется, что нехорошо. Без смены курсора никак не получается. Побеждается применением костыля:

1. Курсор над меткой становится такой же, как над картой. Поэтому перед обновлением карты меняем курсор карты на такой же, как над меткой:

```
// объявляем глобальную переменную
var gCursorCrutch = 0;
//...
// внутри события нажатия на метку
if (gCursorCrutch == 0) {
    gCursorCrutch = gMap.cursors.push('pointer');               
}
//...
```

2. Возвращаем штатный курсор, когда мышь движется над картой.

```
gMap.events.add('mousemove', map_onMouseMove);
//...
function map_onMouseMove(e) {
    if (gCursorCrutch != 0) {
        gCursorCrutch.remove();
        gCursorCrutch = 0;
    }
}
```

Полный рабочий пример:

```js
"use strict";
    
var gMap = 0;
var gObjectManager = 0;
var gCurrentId = 0;
var gCurrentRoute = [];
var gCursorCrutch = 0;

function myOnLoad() {
  ymaps.ready(init);
}

function init() {

  gMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.753960, 37.620393],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: []
  });
  
  gMap.events.add('mousemove', mapOnMouseMove);

  gObjectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({});
  gObjectManager.events.add('click', omOnClick);            
  gMap.geoObjects.add(gObjectManager);
  
  addPoints();
}

function mapOnMouseMove(e) {
    if (gCursorCrutch != 0) {
        gCursorCrutch.remove();
        gCursorCrutch = 0;
    }
}

function omOnClick(e) {

  let objectId = e.get('objectId');
  let placemark = gObjectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
  let n = gCurrentRoute.indexOf(objectId);
  if (n >= 0) {

    //route_del(placemark, n);
    gCurrentRoute.splice(n, 1);

  } else {                                       

    let coords = placemark.geometry.coordinates;
    let latitude = coords[0];
    let longitude = coords[1];                 

    //route_add(placemark, latitude, longitude);   
    gCurrentRoute.push(objectId);

  }

  if (gCursorCrutch == 0) {
    gCursorCrutch = gMap.cursors.push('pointer');               
  }
  update_labels();
}

function update_labels() {

  let placemarks = gObjectManager.objects.getAll();
  placemarks.forEach(function(placemark) {
    let objectId = placemark.id;
    let n = gCurrentRoute.indexOf(objectId);
    let oldIconContent = placemark.properties.iconContent;
    if (n >= 0) {
      placemark.properties.iconContent = "" + n;
    } else {
      placemark.properties.iconContent = "";
    }
  });

  gMap.geoObjects.remove(gObjectManager);
    gMap.geoObjects.add(gObjectManager);
}

function addPoints()
{       
    let json = `
    {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "0",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.818948,
      37.702706
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "1",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.615553,
      37.448752
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "2",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.495323,
      37.578487
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "3",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.9999633,
      37.5260016
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "4",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.481092,
      37.602714
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "5",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.445676,
      37.626026
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "6",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.624398,
      37.45875
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "7",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.615553,
      37.448752
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "8",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.616819,
      37.469458
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "9",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.733346,
      37.697235
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "10",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.718486,
      37.633284
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "11",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.655765,
      37.6310452
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "12",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.67228,
      37.614294
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "13",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.584492,
      37.611994
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "14",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.848402,
      37.379914
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "15",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.835114,
      37.402543
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blackCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "16",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.896731,
      37.519243
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "17",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.684554,
      37.886303
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "18",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.9999633,
      37.5260016
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "19",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.923629,
      38.040652
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "20",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      56.020994,
      37.458184
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "21",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.375352,
      37.785962
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "22",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.551242,
      37.685386
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "23",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.815848,
      37.362729
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "24",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.815848,
      37.362729
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "25",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.856093,
      37.384019
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "26",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.6840806828,
      37.4127423987
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "27",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.845486,
      37.436409
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "28",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.841261,
      37.494422
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon"
      }
      }
      ]
      }  
  `;
  let data = JSON.parse(json);
  gObjectManager.removeAll();
  gObjectManager.add(data);

  gMap.setBounds(gMap.geoObjects.getBounds(),{checkZoomRange:true, zoomMargin:9});
}
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=Map,Placemark,ObjectManager&onload=myOnLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким методом получается динамически изменить содержимое метки:

```
gObjectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {    
  let objectId = e.get('objectId');
  let object = gObjectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
  gObjectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(objectId, {
      preset: 'islands#redIcon'
  });
  object.properties.iconContent = "12";
});
```

```js
"use strict";
    
var gMap = 0;
var gObjectManager = 0;
var gCurrentId = 0;
var gCurrentRoute = [];

function myOnLoad() {
  ymaps.ready(init);
}

function init() {

  gMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.753960, 37.620393],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: []
  });

  gObjectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({});
  
  gObjectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {    
    let objectId = e.get('objectId');
    let object = gObjectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
    gObjectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(objectId, {
        preset: 'islands#redIcon'
    });
    object.properties.iconContent = "12";
  });  
  gMap.geoObjects.add(gObjectManager);
  
  addPoints();
}


function addPoints()
{       
    let json = `
    {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "0",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.818948,
      37.702706
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "1",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.615553,
      37.448752
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "2",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.495323,
      37.578487
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "3",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.9999633,
      37.5260016
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "4",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.481092,
      37.602714
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "5",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.445676,
      37.626026
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "6",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.624398,
      37.45875
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "7",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.615553,
      37.448752
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "8",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.616819,
      37.469458
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "9",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.733346,
      37.697235
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "10",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.718486,
      37.633284
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "11",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.655765,
      37.6310452
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "12",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.67228,
      37.614294
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "13",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.584492,
      37.611994
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "14",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.848402,
      37.379914
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "15",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.835114,
      37.402543
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blackCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "16",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.896731,
      37.519243
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "17",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.684554,
      37.886303
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "18",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.9999633,
      37.5260016
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "19",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.923629,
      38.040652
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "20",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      56.020994,
      37.458184
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "21",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.375352,
      37.785962
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "22",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.551242,
      37.685386
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "23",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.815848,
      37.362729
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "24",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.815848,
      37.362729
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "25",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.856093,
      37.384019
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "26",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.6840806828,
      37.4127423987
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "27",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.845486,
      37.436409
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "28",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
      55.841261,
      37.494422
      ]
      },
      "properties": {},
      "options": {
      "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon"
      }
      }
      ]
      }  
  `;
  let data = JSON.parse(json);
  gObjectManager.removeAll();
  gObjectManager.add(data);

  gMap.setBounds(gMap.geoObjects.getBounds(),{checkZoomRange:true, zoomMargin:9});
}
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=Map,Placemark,ObjectManager&onload=myOnLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пример не рабочий - ткните мышкой и не двигайте ей. Я о таком варианте написал в самом начале. "Если просто щёлкнуть мышью и не двигать ей - ничего не произойдёт."

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле оказалось, что можно сделать примерно так:

когда создаем ObjectManager:

```
myObjectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
myObjectManager.refreshObject = function(object) {
  this.objects.setObjectOptions((object?.id)? object.id : object);
}
```

далее, когда нужно обновить отдельный элемент (пример):

```
const myObject = myObjectManager.objects.getById(objectId);

myObject.properties.iconContent = 'New Icon Content';

myObjectManager.refreshObject(myObject);
```

или

```
const myObject = myObjectManager.objects.getById(objectId);

myObject.properties.iconContent = 'New Icon Content';

myObjectManager.refreshObject(objectId);
```

т.е. `setObjectOptions(objectId)` (только с первым параметром) работает как refresh отдельного объекта